# Finding, and deleting, a rogue Application Insights Web Test

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-application-insights

I have a quite extensive application running under Azure.

As part of the operational management of the application, I have a set of Application Insight instances to provide monitoring, tracking and logging.

The overall application consists of three ASP.NET MVC websites and a Worker Role.  Additionally, I have three instances ("environments") of the application overall deployed (QA, UAT and Production).

I noticed a while back that for one of the App Insight instances (for the same MVC website across all environments) it was quite heavy on the number of `Dependency` data points that is being collected.  Specifically, this is causing me to exceed the 5 million data points included in the monthly quota.

Noting this, I changed the Web Tests (for availability) to hit a different endpoint (one that doesn't invoke the dependencies).

However, I am still seeing the old endpoint being hit.

Digging a little further into this, I believe that I have an old rogue Web Test that is still active, and still hitting the old endpoint.
Issue is - I can't find it.

Is there a way to query, even if via the Powershell Cmdlets, the subscription in an attempt to find this?  I've trawled through the portal and cannot see it anywhere.

Could this be the "Proactive Detection" feature?  If so, can you change the endpoint it monitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely open a support ticket with us.  Check out the [dev support options](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-get-dev-support/) and look at either option 3 or 4. It's preferred you open a support ticket via Azure with a support plan (option 3) if you have one. But, if you don't have a support plan check out option 4 and you can get in contact with us that way.

Comment: Thanks - have opened a ticket of issue type `Quota` for `Application Insights` which is included under my support plan.